# Determine which equation is not equivalent to the equation preceding it. 1 = 2 Fallacie problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem was taken from *Algebra and Trigonometry with Analytic Geometry, 12e by Swokowski E. W. and Cole J. A. p. 68*

We start with:
$$x^2 - x - 2 = x^2 - 4$$
Factorize both sides:
$$(x+1)(x-2) = (x + 2)(x - 2)$$
We divide both sides by $(x-2)$:
$$x + 1 = x + 2$$
Substract $x$:
$$1 = 2$$

I know that $x + 1 = x - 2$ is not equivalent to $(x + 1)(x - 2) = (x + 2)(x - 2)$. Therefore we can't divide both sides by $(x - 2)$.

My question is, why? I've been looking for similar algebra fallacies and most of them includes a division by $0$. But on this particular problem I can't seem to find the reason why we can't divide by $(x - 2)$

Comment: In order two divide by $x-2$ you have to assume that $x\neq 2$. With that in mind, if we assume that $x\neq 2$, we arrive at a false result (namely that $1=2$), which indicates that the original equation does not have any solution for $x\neq 2$. So in a sence, in order for the first equality (and hence all thr ones that follow after the factorization) to be true, you must have $x=2$. Thus when you divide by $x-2$ you're secretly Dividing by $0$

Comment: @pepe369 division by zero and indeterminate form leads to same fallacies . It is better to consider all cases to get desired results.

Comment: You have no justification for what you start with.  It is an equation that might have a solution or might not.  As it turns out, the only solution to your original equation is $x=2$, so you are dividing by $0$, but that is not the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fotis for the answer.

Solving the original equation yields:
$$x^2 - x - 2 = x^2 - 4$$
$$-x - 2 = - 4$$
$$-x = -2$$
$$x = 2$$

If we assume that $x \not = 2$ and we try to simplify the original equality $x^2 - x - 2 = x^2 - 4$ we arrive at the false result $1 = 2$ which means that the original equation only solution is $x = 2$; therefore we can't  divide the equation $(x + 1)(x - 2) = (x + 2)(x - 2)$  by $(x - 2)$ because that will compute to a division by $0$.